# Bootbox alert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

trying to use Bootbox confirmation but i start testing it with `bootbox.alert()`, but it's not working.

I confirm that i have *bootstrab.css*, *bootstrab.js*, *jquery.js* and -*bootbox.min.js* included in the web header:

```
 <link href="{% static "css/patients.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/jquery-ui.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is my button that i want to generate the alert when clicked:

```
<form id='form'  name='delete'  action="{% url 'delete_person' person.id %}"
          method='POST'>

    {% csrf_token %}

    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-link icon'><i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></button>
</form>
```

In same *.html* file i have  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.btn').on('click' , function(){
                 bootbox.alert("hello there!");
                         });
                 });</script>
```

when i click on the button nothing happened,

I confirmed that my browser are able to download the content from CDN, 
not sure where is the issue.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: i don't see anything related to bootbox in the console i used firefox console --> js and used the filter to filter on Bootbox

Comment: You're listening to the form submit button and you've assigned an action to it.  Take a look at this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27328602/185034

Comment: if the page is being rendered by JS (Angular, etc), you might try $('.btn').live('click',function(){ ...

Comment: tried with `.live` and `.addEventListener` , but not working

Comment: You also have the order incorrect - bootbox.js needs to be loaded after bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543979/bootbox-confirm-dialog-problems)

this works for me :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn#del").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lHref = $('form#form1').attr('action');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(confirmed) {
        if(confirmed) {
            window.location.href = lHref;
        }
    });
});
})
</script>

<button type='submit'  onclick="bootbox.confirm();" id="del" class='btn btn-xs btn-link icon'><i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></button>
    </form></td>
```